# Shopware installation error: Identifier DB not initialized yet

Tags: installation, shopware

After installation wizard is finished I get this error.

Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

```
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Identifier DB not initialized yet
File: /.../recovery/install/src/ContainerProvider.php
Line: 162
```

Is there is some configuration file where I can set DB params? I had insert all params via installation wizard.

Comment: There are 2 versions of shopware. From git repo and zip version from official website. Which one do you have?

Comment: Zip version from official site. . . Is version can be different depending on zip or git?

Comment: Zip version is more like for show off to see how shopware looks like. And git version is for further development. So for zip version you need to create a database and you need to have a user for database who has all rights on to it. And then you can start the installation

Comment: I had only created database without new user, only root. This look to me as problem? Can it be?

Comment: Not 100% sure. But try to create a new user and grant all rights to that database

Comment: Did you make it?

Comment: @lewis4u I had remove php and reinstall again. This had done job. Mysql user was not problem.

Comment: Btw, after composer install, project not working again. It is working with ziped vendor folder.

Comment: Yeah I had a lot of problems too.... zip version breaks with any composer command. You need to git clone the version from git repo and install ant and then it will work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In file recovery/install/src/ContainerProvider.php
Add 2 strings:

1. In use-section

`use Shopware\Recovery\Update\Utils;`

2.Inside the register-function:

```
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
            $conn = Utils::getConnection(SW_PATH);

            return $conn;
        };
```

Comment: Would you mind submitting that as a Merge Request to the Shopware Code? It does seem like a nice fix

Comment: I was facing the same issue and this suggestion helped me install Shopware on my hosting provider! Any reason why we would not have this fix in in the Shopware source code?

Comment: This helped a lot, it still was a problem in the current shopware6-version