# Slim Application Error while installing shopware 6

Tags: shopware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfQ9H.png)Trying to install shopware user edition 6.1.5 for our application but facing an error. Tried with even 6.1.4 version also but the same issue. Tried the both the 6.1.5 and 6.1.4 versions with all the three PHP versions 7.2.29 7.3.16 as well as 7.4.4 on Ubuntu 18.0.4. 
Even followed the instructions by increasing the max_execution_time = 600 secondsmemory_limit = 1024M/512M but no luck
Even followed the below-mentioned method but wasn't successful either. 
[Shopware installation error: Identifier DB not initialized yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637033/shopware-installation-error-identifier-db-not-initialized-yet)

Any help/ideas pointing to solve this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "but facing an error"
Which error do you face?
Is there any log file or output you could provide?

Comment: error- "identifier db not initialized yet". I added the screenshot for the same. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the session is left. You should check your default session configurations