# Shopware 6 Installation error: Identifier dbal not initialized yet

Tags: php, docker, shopware6

In setting up the database installation on localhost, When I get to the database Installation section I have this error

```
Error
Received an error message.
URL: importDatabase
Message: Internal Server Error

Please try to fix this error and restart the update.
Response

Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:
Details
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Identifier dbal not initialized yet
File: /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/recovery/Install/src/ContainerProvider.php
Line: 196
```

I have tried several solutions to no avail, especially this solution here a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637033/shopware-installation-error-identifier-db-not-initialized-yet)
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Which Shopware version do you use? How did you start the installation?

Comment: Shopware 6 @Alex

Comment: Would you mind providing more details of step by step instructions of what you have set up already. E.g. If you have a docker installation, what's the docker image like? What command are you running? How does your docker-compose file look like if that's what you are doing?

Comment: @augsteyer I'm using docker/dockware, the compose file is [here](https://pastebin.com/neddnhPZ) Everything works until it is time to do the database setup in the browser, then I get the error. this only happens when I use the essentials option of shopware, I have been learning on the development version for the time being, though I will still need to figure out the production/essentials version and use that soon, thank you

Comment: you should update your question with all these details, most users will not read comments to figure out how to help. Secondly, there is another step here. The essentials does not come with Shopware. Based on your question, it seems you are trying to install it. Did you pull it via git or zip? Did you add the database details in the `.env` file? I hear this issue happened on lower versions of PHP, is it possible for you to upgrade the compose file to 8.0?

Comment: I have never checked the .env file so yet, I will do that and update the question again. thank you